# Mysql version of mysql count

Tags: php, mysql, count, mysqli

I am just slowly moving from mysql to mysqli and am trying to code a new website using mysqli. I am trying to count the number of rows, and am trying to convert the following mysql query to mysqli but am scratching my head a bit as mysqli appears to be quite different in the way it does things.

```
 $result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`");
  $row = $result->fetch_row();
    echo '#: ', $row[0];
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be doing this the long winded way but I tend to do the following for general queries

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($count);
$query->fetch();
$query->close();
```

$count now holds the value you wanted.

Comment: I tend to prepare all my stataments (this may be less efficient, I have no idea) but it gets me in the habbit so I never forget to write prepared statements (as most of my queries I write use data inputted in forms.

Comment: I get the following error for some reason Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\easyphp\www\twinfocus\managealbums.php on line 32

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\easyphp\www\twinfocus\managealbums.php on line 32

Comment: have you created your mysqli connection? Mine happens to be stored in the $mysqli object.

Comment: Thanks, thats got it !, I forgot I need to ref the connection in mysqli.